# _vimrc getting renamed to _vimrc.2014

Tags: vim

I noticed that for whatever reason, my _vimrc wasn't being loaded this morning. I keep my entire `vim` directory saved to my Google Drive to the location I specify in my _vimrc. I didn't worry about it since I'd recently backed it up, but now when I dump it into my `vim` folder, whenever I start up gVim, it looks like it renames it to _vimrc.2014.

I can't find anything about this behavior, is it normal? It doesn't really affect me too much since it still gets source, but I just want to know why it's doing that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim certainly is not doing this. I'm not certain it's causing YOUR problem, but Google Drive has problems replacing files with a new file of the same name. Under the hood, that is exactly what Vim is doing when it writes a file with default settings. See https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_use/jkw_nnHz9cE/discussion : you can use either the 'backupskip' or 'writebackup' options to force Vim to write the file directly instead of replacing it with a new file when editing inside your Google Drive folder. I'm using this line in my .vimrc to accomplish the task:

```
let &backupskip.=','.expand('$HOME/Google\ Drive/').'*'
```